# I got a Stack Overflow Error here, but I don't know why

Tags: java, stack-overflow

I have a binary search tree and want to find the node with the specified value. This is my code for this, but I get a Stack Overflow Error. I hope, someone can tell me why. 
My code:

```
public TreeNode findNodebyKey2(int val) {
    if (val == key) {
        return this;
    } else if (val < key) {
            return this.left.findNodebyKey2(val);
    } else if(val > key){
            return this.right.findNodebyKey2(val);
    }
    return this;
}
```

Comment: debug your program. your `val == key` condition is never being satisfied and you are running out of stack frames

Comment: Your are using a recursive calls which leads to a stack overflow error. Because whenever a method is called stack will be allocated to the stack to perform the operation.

Comment: 1. Check if you have properly inserted data left and right. It ONLY works if the tree is correct. 2. I also see a NullPointerException when left or right is missing(which must be at the leaves in case of no match) 3. return this would never be reached, remove that. 4. If 1, 2 are correct, StackOverflow should only be the case when data is huge or exceeds memory.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you have posted, you can get StackOverflowException only in 2 situations:

1. Your tree is very deep (thousands of levels). Thus you run out of stack space.
2. Your tree is not actualy a tree, but a graph (it has cycles, e.g. given a current node, then one of the children is the ancestor of the current node).

I'd bet on 2.